# How to load animated webp image in a `UIImageView`

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, webp

I need to show an animated webp image in my app.
I've already seen some frameworks like [AnimatedWebP](https://github.com/tattn/AnimatedWebP) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), but none of these works as it should.
Someone knows a way to show an animated webp image (like a gif) into an `UIImageView`?

Comment: Why exactly do those libraries don't work as "they should"?

Comment: If you give me a URL of a webp gif, I will send you the working code.

Comment: I have a webp gif saved locally within the project and I should show it in a UIImageView